# Qlik in Visual Studio plugin gives websocket error and define() error

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, qlikview, qliksense

I am getting started with qlik desktop and I have connected to the desktop via Visual Studio plugin. I have added 2 sheets to visual studio, but when i debug to localhost, I get errors

In .js file...

```
var config = {
    host: window.location.hostname,
    prefix: '/',
    port: window.location.port,
    isSecure: window.location.protocol === "https:"
};
require.config( {
     baseUrl: (config.isSecure ? "https://" : "http://") + config.host +       (config.port ? ":" + config.port : "") + config.prefix + "resources"
});


require(["js/qlik"], function(qlik) {
  // open the app
  var app = qlik.openApp('c31e2aba-3b46-4b13-8b87-c5c2514dea1d', config);   
    //someone please tell me what this id is and where it comes from 
    because I c&p'd off of the tutorials and idk what goes here
});
```

In VS:

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphMain" runat="server">
    <div class="qlik-embed" data-qlik-appid="\\apfs01\users\rbeets\Documents\Qlik\Sense\Apps\app1.qvf" data-qlik-objid="ZCJjkN></div>
    <div class="qlik-embed" data-qlik-appid="\\apfs01\users\rbeets\Documents\Qlik\Sense\Apps\app2.qvf" data-qlik-objid="JRcLVC"></div>
</asp:Content>
```

and the errors 1 and 2:

> Websocket connection to 'ws://localhost......aspx' failed. Error during Websocket handshake. Unexpected response code: 404
>
> Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module      ...from require.js:6
>   1 View Tags : localhostContent tagged with localhost, visual studio pluginContent tagged with visual studio plugin, websocketContent tagged with websocket, mismatched anonymous define()Content tagged with mismatched anonymous define()

Comment: Are you following a tutorial? My guess is that the id you have in openApp() is an QS appID from Sense Server. Do you have a server running or just the QS client? If you use the client you should type the name of the app instead of an ID.

Comment: yes, i was following a tutorial (just for the desktop atm though) and i found the correct appID and no more websocket error! Thank you. Now onto the other errors lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer at the following link, which gives directions to finding the appId via either the server or the desktop(localhost) connection....

https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/1.0/Subsystems/Workbench/Content/BuildingWebsites/HowTos/qswb_mup_obtainobjectid.htm